# How to add multiple values to a multilevel dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I tried rubberduckying this, but I give up. I don't understand why this keeps failing me. I have the following dictionary template I want to fill

```
 testfile = {'locations':
        {'location_name1":
                {'document_title1': 'title_value1',
                'page_nr1': 'text_value1'}
        }}
```

I have the following code that triest to insert multiple values into it. This represents the code that I'm currently working with.

```
testfile = {}


locatie = 0


while location != 5:
   page_nr = 0
   while page_nr != 3:
      testfile = testfile + {'location':{'location_naam' + str(location): 
      {'page_nr' + str(page_nr):'text_value'+ str(pagina_nr)}}}
      page_nr += 1
   location += 1
```

This keeps resulting in the code overwriting testfile every loop. But i want to add the values and basically getting 3 location_names with 5 document_titles/page_nrs per location_name.

How do i achieve this?

EDIT

The desired output would be

```
{'location': 
   {'location_naam0': {
      'page_nr0': 'text_value0',
      'page_nr1': 'text_value1',
      'page_nr1': 'text_value1'}}, 
   {'location_naam1': {
      'page_nr0': 'text_value0',
      'page_nr1': 'text_value1',
      'page_nr1': 'text_value1'}},
   {'location_naam2': {
      'page_nr0': 'text_value0',
      'page_nr1': 'text_value1',
      'page_nr1': 'text_value1'}},
   {'location_naam3': {
      'page_nr0': 'text_value0',
      'page_nr1': 'text_value1',
      'page_nr1': 'text_value1'}},
   {'location_naam4': {
      'page_nr0': 'text_value0',
      'page_nr1': 'text_value1',
      'page_nr1': 'text_value1'}}
  }
```

Comment: I think its better to declare `testfile` as list and append the dict each time.

Comment: Your desired output has duplicate keys in dictionary which is not possible.

Comment: @Adam: Please see my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
print({
    'location': {
        "location_naam{}".format(i): {
            "page_nr{}".format(k): "text_value{}".format(k)
            for k in range(2)
        }
        for i in range(4) 
    }

})


out:
{
    "location": {
        "location_naam0": {
            "page_nr0": "text_value0",
            "page_nr1": "text_value1"
        },
        "location_naam1": {
            "page_nr0": "text_value0",
            "page_nr1": "text_value1"
        },
        "location_naam2": {
            "page_nr0": "text_value0",
            "page_nr1": "text_value1"
        },
        "location_naam3": {
            "page_nr0": "text_value0",
            "page_nr1": "text_value1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the correct solution to my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here I've solved like making a list of all dicts :

```
testfile = []

location = 0
while location != 5:
    page_nr = 0
    while page_nr != 3:
         testfile.append( {'location':{'location_naam' +str(location):
             {'page_nr' +str(page_nr):'text_value'+str(pagina_nr)}}})
         page_nr += 1
    location += 1
 print(testfile)
```

It O/Ps like :

```
[{'location': {'location_naam0': {'page_nr0': 'text_value0'}}}, 
 {'location': {'location_naam0': {'page_nr1': 'text_value1'}}}, 
 {'location': {'location_naam0': {'page_nr2': 'text_value2'}}}, 
 {'location': {'location_naam1': {'page_nr0': 'text_value0'}}},                          
 {'location': {'location_naam1': {'page_nr1': 'text_value1'}}}, 
 {'location': {'location_naam1': {'page_nr2': 'text_value2'}}},      
 {'location': {'location_naam2': {'page_nr0': 'text_value0'}}}, 
 {'location': {'location_naam2': {'page_nr1': 'text_value1'}}}, 
 {'location': {'location_naam2': {'page_nr2': 'text_value2'}}}, 
 {'location': {'location_naam3': {'page_nr0': 'text_value0'}}}, 
 {'location': {'location_naam3': {'page_nr1': 'text_value1'}}}, 
 {'location': {'location_naam3': {'page_nr2': 'text_value2'}}},
 {'location': {'location_naam4': {'page_nr0': 'text_value0'}}}, 
 {'location': {'location_naam4': {'page_nr1': 'text_value1'}}}, 
 {'location': {'location_naam4': {'page_nr2': 'text_value2'}}}]
```

Comment: OIs it possible to merge the values of the page_nrs under the same key? so that it only outputs 5 location_names instead of 15? For the sake of this representative code it works, but the live version it has 20+ pages per location, and that will fill the dict with unneccesary extra lines

Comment: can you then add a piece of your sample o/p.Still I used your logic only, What I have done is just grouped your all dicts to a list.We can help you if you give more idea about your o/p

Comment: Added the desired output in my question

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue using this piece of code. I basically added lists in the dictionary to make everything work.

```
while x != 4: # documentniveau
    results[0]['locaties'].append({'locatie' + str(x): []})
    y = 0
    while y != 2: # paginaniveau
        results[0]['locaties'][x]['locatie'+str(x)].append({'pagenr': y})
        y += 1
    x += 1
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "locaties": [
      {
        "locatie0": [
          {
            "pagenr": 0
          },
          {
            "pagenr": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "locatie1": [
          {
            "pagenr": 0
          },
          {
            "pagenr": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "locatie2": [
          {
            "pagenr": 0
          },
          {
            "pagenr": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "locatie3": [
          {
            "pagenr": 0
          },
          {
            "pagenr": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: But this is not what your expected in your Question.